# Application session cookie is replicated after session timeout

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, cookies

I'm facing a problem with my web application.
I run a Spring\Java application on Tomcat, with the use of cookies. The problem happens when my session expires. 
The application correctly generates a new cookie and writes it in the URL, but the cookie is replicated. On the next request the expired cookie is deleted, but on the first one I have two cookies.

So, in steps:

1. My user logs in the application, the application sets the cookie and appends it in the request:

   - http://localhost/myapp;cookie=111111?param1=1......
2. If i wait for the session to expire, on the next request the url gets changed to:

   - http://localhost/myapp;cookie=111111;cookie=2222222?param1=1.....
3. On the next request the url goes to:

   - http://localhost/myapp;cookie=2222222?param1=1.....

This is my SecurityConfig:

```
final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        tokenRepository.setHeaderName("TOOLBIZ-CSRF-TOKEN");
        tokenRepository.setParameterName("toolbiz_csrf");

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/main/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/main").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/main/logout").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/errore").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/errore/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .and().sessionManagement().enableSessionUrlRewriting(true)
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/main/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
        .deleteCookies("cookie")                  <-----------------------
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/jsp/403.jsp")
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

I tought about something like:

```
.and().sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/").sessionFixation().newSession()
```

But I don't know if that's right.

If you need some other information don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The cookies are generated in the web.xml file:

```
<session-config>
   <cookie-config>
    <name>toolBizCookie</name><!-- default is jsessionid -->
    <http-only>true</http-only>
   </cookie-config>
   <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
```

Comment: Cookies has a larger life than a session. How did you generate a new cookie?

Comment: I have added the required informations in the question... It doesn't seem to be a lifetime problem, as the old one disappears from the url on the very next request.